# Simple tag helper "suddenly" no longer renders properly (only in production, only for one page)

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, razor, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

As the title states, I'm having a finicky issue with .NET Core 2.2. I'm using tag helpers all over, but on the specific page that I'm having trouble with, it's actually the most simple use-case of all:

```
<a class="logout" asp-page="/Admin/Logout">Logout</a>
```

Some relevant notes:

- As of yesterday, it worked in all environments without any issues.
- This morning I made some changes seemingly unrelated to this page, and published again.
- In the published version (on Azure), the tag helpers **for this page only** don't render, but instead appear in the source code as literals.  (e.g. `<a asp-page="..."></a>`)
- Still works without issue locally.

Here is the directory structure. The page in question is `/Admin/Index.cshtml`:

[image]

And my `_ViewImports.cshtml` (which again, I haven't changed in months):

```
@using redacted
@namespace redacted.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Comment: Did you clean local solution to make sure you are not using already built files? Did you also try to run this locally in 'release' version?

Comment: Yes and yes, to no avail.

Comment: Does [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8072) help? There's a link to a SO question also. Seems very similar to what you are experiencing, but not sure it explains difference between non-production and production.

Comment: @CardiDeMonacoJr Thanks! I've actually gotten so frustrated that I ended up moving the entire thing to 3.0 (which apparently should work according to that thread you've shared), but still no luck. Banging my head against a wall.

Comment: Turn it off and turn it back on again? XD 

Actually, what about deleting the file, recreating it, and copying the code back in? If I think of anything else, I will be sure to post.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly adding the taghelper to the `.chshtml` file has solved this for me in the past. Unfortunately I am not aware of why this issue occurs randomly. In my specific use case,we were using custom and third party tag helpers which we suspect was causing the issues.

Try adding this line to the `/Admin/Index.cshtml` file:

```cs
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but unfortunately this did not work either.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: No, I did not. I ended up just using a relative URL instead of tag helpers.