# Partial not running in .NET 7 when deployed to Azure

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm running an ASP.NET Core 7 app that I've written. I've pretty much used the basics from a basic setup of a new ASP.NET Core app in Visual Studio 2022. When I run it locally, everything is working as intended.  I've added a bit of code to the _LogonPartial.cshtml.

When I run it locally, I got everything running correctly.

```html
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">BWDWeb</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/Users/Pictures">Pics</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" title="Manage" href="/Identity/Account/Manage">Hello wallace.b.mcclure@gmail.com!</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="/Identity/Account/Logout">
                <button  type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
            <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8GZuOj8G4EJKpkUu0YwgwQUebAMzZHDWLJlpWl8yStyoJraAREx1GrNPYY-OwqrmMSnrko3UQ-8LV4XSBT4TFtwdJnNSfUl1vLWrh6CpIC9kyMbzvpUDVoOJDOQk5Tr7GmF3wdADP5Lo3OOmEsxcRl9Vl5u3bGFAUh52JGx2mgRVH9sFp3pcKSSmbaupMkq3wA" /></form>
        </li>
    </ul>
    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

When I run it in azure, I get this:

```html
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">BWDWeb</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Users/Pictures">Pics</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Here is the content of my _LogonPartial

```
    @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
    @using BWDWeb.Models
    @inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
    @inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
    
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
    @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a  class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity?.Name!</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <form class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Page("/", new { area = "" })" method="post" >
                <button  type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
            </form>
        </li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
        </li>
    }
    </ul>
```

I don't know why my code isn't running on Azure. I'm trying to figure out why. I've rebuilt, I've redeployed, and I've had no success.

I've created another web app in VS 2022, and deployed it, and everything works properly. I think the problem is somewhere in my code, but danged I can't see what I've mucked up and I don't know where to start. Any suggestions on how to get my `_LogonPartial` working again are appreciated.

Comment: It's not just partials that aren't working. None of your tag helpers are being processed. There's another question about this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63693720/simple-tag-helper-suddenly-no-longer-renders-properly-only-in-production-onl. Not sure it it helps...

Comment: Did you publish your built file like "DLL" files instead of those cshtml files?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but going into my publish settings, checking "Remove additional files at destination", and then redeploying has solved this problem for the moment.  I did add the tagHelpers directives as suggested by @Mike Brind's link and redeployed previously, but that in and of itself didn't solve the problem.  Doing both together seems to have solved the problem, though I do not know that adding the taghelpers lines into several files really did anything.

I also did a "clean" somewhere in the process this morning, but I think I had tried that yesterday to no avail.  hopefully, someone can better explain what happened.  Hopefully, the change the deployment settings and deleting the files will help someone else.